# Blazor wasm uploading file to asp.net core web api

Tags: upload, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I read the [MS tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly) about Blazor file uploads, and I am still unclear what is the recommended way to upload file to a server. A file is an XML document, if it matters.

What I already did: On Blazor client (wasm) I have InputFile component to allow user to upload single file. After that I read the file content in byte[] array:

```
const long maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024; // max 1MB
using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
await e.File.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize).CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
```

and then I attach this to my request model used in POST (web api):

```
public class UploadModel
{
    public SomeObject Data { get; set; }
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
}
```

This works, but the MS article states that we should not read the file content in memory, which is what I am doing. So, how can I pass this content to my asp.net core server directly, and then read it on server? I do not want to save this file anywhere, I need to send it to server, server will process it, and then store relevant info to database.

Comment: In WASM the best approach is to let your uploading happen through JavaScript. Once written for WASM, might as well use the same for server side. The biggest issue (bar security) is the memory footprint. If you try and upload big files your browser tab will run out of memory and throw an exception.

Comment: Have you had any luck finding an answer on other sources? I'm doing the exact same thing and have the exact same question. :)